# How well do rabbits remember things?

Tags: rabbits, psychology

I got my rabbit from the animal shelter around four years ago. Today I was playing with her, and she seems so happy that I began to wonder if she remembers her time that she spent at the animal shelter. Is there a possibility that she remembers things that have happened so long ago?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say how often rabbits review memories I can say that rabbits can and do form memories of unpleasant situations and respond to them.  Before posting this answer, I looked for scientific references (memory lagomorph) but did not find anything significant.  The following answer is based on personal experience.

We adopted Harmony (black and white dutch) from our local shelter, there is a large room that bunny's are taken to for the ["bunny romp"](https://wpahumane.org/bunny-romps) and this is where we first met Harmony.  She was extremely cuddly; climb in your lap and snuggle in for a nap, cuddly. We took her home that day. We got home and she was distinctly less cuddly, still very friendly but there was a clear difference in her behavior.  About 16 months later there was a reunion for rabbits who had been adopted at the shelter, in the same big room where they have the bunny romp. Harmony was suddenly miss snuggles all over again.  In the past 5 years we have had her at several 'bring your bunny' parties, taken her to pet stores, and taken her camping in seven eastern US states. She is always a bit more reserved when out, but on the now several occasions when she is at an event at the shelter, she is that same supper snugly bunny when we are there.

There is no doubt in my mind that she can tell when we are at the shelter, and that she remembers it.